# How can i deploy Session Bean on another computer with Client JSP/Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb

Hello Everybody i'm new in EJB3, i know how to deploy Session Bean (Stateless or stateful) on Glassfish server in one computer. My question is: how can i deploy session bean on Computer A and Deploy Servlet or JSP on Computer B?
It mean 
Computer A have Session Bean Source
and Computer B have Servlet or JSP source.
if use 1 computer i can use @EJB dependency inject lookup Session Bean
but on another computer how can i do it for client code?
Example for 1 computer

```
@EJB
private StatelessRemote remote ;

double Dosomething= remote.Dosomething();

out.println(Dosomething);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763960/accessing-a-stateless-ejb-from-another-instance-of-glassfish/10194057#10194057

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a "client jar" with the remote interfaces, deploy in on the client
2. Provide the app server client jar (not necessary in your scenario)
3. Provide a `jndi.properties` on the classpath with the following content (assuming GlassFish to GlassFish communication):

   ```
   java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming
   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl
   org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=<hostname>
   org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700
   ```
4. Use the `mappedName` attribute of the `@EJB` annotation to specify the global JNDI name of the target Remote EJB component (If there is no `jndi-name` set in sun-ejb-jar.xml - or no sun-ejb-jar.xml at all - the global jndi-name defaults to the fully qualified Remote 3.0 Business interface class name) :

   ```
   @EJB(mappedName="com.acme.app.StatelessRemote")
   private StatelessRemote remote;
   ```

#### Resources

- [GlassFish EJB FAQ](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html)
- http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/ejb3/EJB3-2-Session-Beans.pdf