# Deploying maven project on glassfish using deploy command

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a java ee application with maven, when i build the project then deploy the ear generated on target folder, i try to signup to the application so i have to call a locale EJB Session (ConfigUser) , i get the following error:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/myproject-ear/myproject-ejb-1.0/UserFacade!myproject.service.ConfigUser' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: myproject-ear] at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518) at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455) at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:79) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411) at
```

I tried deploying using the command `call asadmin --host localhost --user admin deploy --force "C:\myproject\target\myproject-ear-1.0.ear"`, i also tried deploying from glassfish administration console, but the problem persist.

It works fine when i deploy from netbeans, knowing that the project is structured in the pom file like this:

```
  <modules>
    <module>myproject-ear</module>
    <module>myproject-ejb</module>
    <module>myproject-web</module>
  </modules>
```

This is the jsp page :

```
Context c = new InitialContext();
ConfigUser configUser = (ConfigUser) c.lookup("java:global/myproject-ear/myproject-ejb-1.0/ConfigUser!myproject.service.ConfigUser");
```

Comment: How did you build your ear? If I recall, [order is important when build from the project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). How about trying putting `<module>myproject-ear</module>` at the end, build the project (which will sequentially build the ejb > the web > the ear) and deploy using your script? Another hint would be to make sure that the EAR deployed by Netbeans is the same as the one used in your script

Comment: Have you checked [this answer + link to blogpost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705922/ejb3-glassfish-jndi-lookup)

Answer (score 1):

Since there was no answer to this problem, i'm answering my own question, after research i've found the reason to the `javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed` problem, the EJB `ConfigUser` that i was looking for was not correctly mapped to the JNDI name, so after the deploy i checked the server log and the JNDI name was :

```
java:global/myproject-ear-1.0/myproject-ejb-1.0/ConfigUser!myproject.service.ConfigUser
```

instead of :

```
java:global/myproject-ear/myproject-ejb-1.0/ConfigUser!myproject.service.ConfigUser
```