# How to target a specific glassfish server

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

Is there a way to target a specific glassfish server instance and open a module that is deployed on that server? That is, regardless of whether that module is deployed on another server in the same cluster.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone in the future wants an answer to this, I used this which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194057/1691662):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");

// Defaults to localhost.   
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "127.0.0.1");
// Defaults to 3700.
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
RemoteBean beanInstance = (RemoteBean) ic.lookup("java:global/ExampleEJB/RemoteBean!com.example.RemoteBean");
```