# How to access EJB on remote server?

Tags: java, glassfish, jndi, lookup

I am using a GlassFish-3.1.2 server running in my subnet (192.168.1.3:3700). I already deployed an enterprise app including an EJB in which i defined a business method. Now I want to remotely access the EJB from my java application client. How do i have to setup the JNDI resp. the InitialContext object for doing the lookup of the EJB ? How do I need to define the properties? Btw. I had to run "asadmin enabled-secure-admin" in order to make the GlassFish server work on the LAN. Probably I also need to send my credentials with the properties ?

Here's my current "solution", which seems to be completley wrong :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.1.3");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);

TestentityFacadeRemote tfr = (TestentityFacadeRemote)ctx.lookup("java:global/TestEE/TestEE-ejb/TestentityFacadeRemote");
```

When I run this programm, it just waits infinitely...

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3783501/1037626 - there's some more properties described there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the host and port directy by System.setProperty() and using the default constructor for initializing the InitialContext(). Note that the following lines should be the very first in your program / main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.1.3");
    System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    TestentityFacadeRemote tfr = (TestentityFacadeRemote)ctx.lookup("java:global/TestEE/TestEE-ejb/TestentityFacadeRemote!com.acme.remote.TestentityFacade");
}
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: for the `IIOP` lookup, did you configure ORB ->IIOP, or JNDI resources in Glassfish?

Comment: I only configured ORB->IIOP with the server's ip address. I didn't change anything on the default JNDI settings.