# Deploying to multiple instances of Glassfish, breaking up my EAR

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, remote-access, ejb-3.1, ear

I have a small EAR-JEE6-application, it consists of 3 Modules ( EAR + EJB + WEB ).
There are 3 files : ear, jar and war - the ear-file holds the jar and the war file.

My Question:
I would like to set up 2 glassfish servers on 2 different machines ( IP-1 and IP-2 ), I would like to deploy the EJB ( jar-file ) on IP-1 and the WEB ( war-file ) on IP-2.

My Web-project has a servlet that is dependent on a Stateless bean in my EJB-project, injected. I cannot get my head around this.

How can the web-project find the stateless bean in the EJB-project ?
I would need some kind of lookup-service that is 'global' ( where I can enter all IP-adressses ) - just guessing here.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Java Naming and Directory Interface ([JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/getStarted/overview/index.html)).

You'll have to lookup your beans manually in a way like this:

```
Context ic = new InitialContext();
Object o = ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/Foo");
```

A little more detail can be found here: [Accessing EJB Components in a Remote GlassFish Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beanv/index.html) or in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829922/how-to-access-ejb-on-remote-server).

Comment: Thanks.But if I put these lines in the Servlet, how will it find the 'java:comp/env/ejb/Foo' if it is deployed on another IP-adress ?

Comment: try {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            CapitalBeanRemote bean = (CapitalBeanRemote) context.lookup(
                    "java:global/RemoteEJBModule/CapitalBean");
            messageTextField.setText(bean.getCapital("Japan"));
            context.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

The web-project must be dependent on the EJB-project because CapitalBeanRemote is a part of the EJB-project ?