# Easy way to access to a remote ejb located in another server

Tags: glassfish, ejb, jndi

This is my first question in Stack Overflow so I expect it will not be too much simple. I've been looking around Internet for a good solution but by now I don't have it.

I am a very begginer to EJB, JNDI and Java EE world in general, but on the last months I've been able to do some acceptable things in this environment. Now I am focusing a problem at work and by now the solution is not as good as I would like.

The scenario is this: I have a EAR application running in Glassfih 3.1.2. I have declared EJBs within this EAR app with stateless beans offering methods through a remote Interface.

This is my Remote Bean running in a server called server1, for example

```
package com.booreg;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import com.booreg.IMyRemoteBean;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyRemoteBean implements IMyRemoteBean
{
    @Override
    public String helloWorld()
    {
        return "Hi what's up boy";
    }
}
```

This is the interface for it

```
package com.booreg;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface IMyRemoteBean
{
    public String helloWorld();
}
```

Then I have a second EAR app that **must run imperatively on another server**, called server2. The second APP is using JSF and Managed Beans. We have a Managed Bean acting as a remote client of MyRemoteBeanRemote, as this:

```
package com.nucleus;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import com.booreg.IMyRemoteBean;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyManagedBean
{
    @EJB( name="TheRef") IMyRemoteBean myRemoteBean;

    public String getPhrase() { return myRemoteBean.helloWorld(); }
}
```

I've arrived to the point that this works declaring an ejb-ref inside WEB-INF/sun-web.xml file in my web project.

```
<ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>TheRef</ejb-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:server1:3700#java:global/booreg/booreg.ejb/MyRemoteBean!com.booreg.IMyRemoteBean</jndi-name>
</ejb-ref>
```

I understand that with this sun-web.xml file the jndi-name makes the second app to know where to locate the ejb implementation located at first app. But here I have some questions:

1. It's necessary to declare one ejb-ref entry for each EJB interface I have in my project ?
2. How can I avoid making a static reference to server/port (server1:3700 during development) inside sun-web.xml ? When this will go into production I will have to change manually the sever name for each  ?? This sounds bizarre. Can I use some kind of variable at server side to specify server/port ?

I expect I have explained myself well enough.

Many thanks

**Update:** finally, thanks to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614802/how-can-i-deploy-session-bean-on-another-computer-with-client-jsp-servlet) I see that is possible to make references to the ejb server (server1) creating a jndi.properties file inside my classpath. This file should contain lines like this.

```
java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming
java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=server1
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700
```

But I am still facing problems. When deploying the application appear the next exception at server1 an I can't deploy the application.

```
ADVERTENCIA: IOP00100006: Class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension is not Serializable
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: ADVERTENCIA: IOP00100006: Class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension is not Serializable  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 6 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy117.notSerializable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ORBUtility.throwNotSerializableForCorba(ORBUtility.java:783)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:697)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputObject.java:545)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAbstractObject(Util.java:493)
    ...
```

Anybody has any idea ?

Comment: If you would lookup the remote ejb via jndi yourself in code you could use server jvm variables for port and server. Maybe its possible to access jvm variables within sun-web.xml. I don't know if thats possible.

Comment: I like to keep code as clean and simple as possible. For this reason I don't like to use lookup inside my code where @EJB makes the work easier.

Comment: Have you considered organizing the two instances in a cluster?

Comment: Not yet. I have 2 problems for that: 1st) I have never done it. 2nd) The 2 servers have a firewall between them to block traffic potentially dangerous. One of this servers is a public internet site. The second one is an internal server of our enterprise. I am not sure if this firewall can cause problems to create the cluster.

Comment: how is the lookup for `org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost` achieved?  Server1 has to have Server2 registered in its DNS to do the lookup?

Comment: Server1 has to be able to "see" Server2 by DNS lookup or directly by the IP adress...

Answer (score 0):

@dgisbert

In the last comment you mentioned , that one server is a public and other one is Internal Server of your enterprise. Well calling the Application layer from a public server is not a best practise. It means you are directly giving access to your critical business layer. I would suggest rather to have a Web Service Layer on top of your EJB calls so every call from Public site has to come through WebServer -> App Server. This way you can higly reduce the risk of attacks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see the reason that is better to have an intermediate Web-Service layer instead of having remote EJB calls. Through remote EJB calls I am controlling which parts of my application are visible remotely through the remote interface.

Comment: @dgisbert - its not about what services you expose - its about giving access to your Enterprise Business Layer to External Parties directly.Typical Architectural Suggestions would be to have a DMZ layer between External and Internal Systems (ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/web/whitepapers/r_wp_securityrichwebapps.pdf).. Google/Bing Search for Securing_Enterprise_Web_Applications_at_the_Source. Its a lengthy document but do take to time to read it.A hacker (Genius guys ? ) may exploit this vulnerability and attack your layer.they keep coming with new approaches

Comment: Thanks again for your comments. I'm not a security specialist, but I'm concerned about security. I've downloaded the document you mention. It's long, but I'll take a look.

About the DMZ, we already have server1 in a DMZ. So, we can control all traffic between server1 and server2 through our firewall. I called it public because we allow web connections on server1 (of course our pages are password-protected) and between server1 and server2 we allow only remote ejb calls. So, IMHO it's the same to have a Web Service Layer bewteen server1 and server2 that having remote EJB service layer.